# navigationController pop incorrect transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am presenting new `viewController` through `navigationController` with:

```
PTAgencyClients *pushedController = [[PTAgencyClients alloc] initWithNibName:@"PTAgencyClients"
                                                                      bundle:nil
                                                                      agency:agency];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:pushedController 
                                       animated:YES];
```

and from this `PTAgencyClients` I am trying to pop this `viewController` with:

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Somehow when I pop it, it haven't this slight from-left-to-right animation. I am experimented a little and I seen mighty transition and in other cases transition of previous `viewController` from  atop of this `PTAgencyClients`. What can initiate this behaviour?
**Update**
It Happens on both device and simulator.

Comment: Is this happening on a device or on a simulator? I'm thinking it's simply a lag because there's a lot of computation going on. However if you're using the simulator, this should not be an issue